# using a child class in place of a parent class with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, dynamic-binding

so I have a class hierarchy that looks like this:

> Oscillator --> AdvancingOscillator --> ViralOscillator
>
> Magnifier --> OsciMag

And OsciMag also inherits from Oscillator (couldnt get the formatting right, sorry if thats confusing). The problem arises when I try to make a heterogeneous collection of OsciMags by passing a dereferenced pointer (typed to oscillator but potentially holding an address of a derived class) to the OsciMag constructor. I have a number of copy constructors that look like this:

```
OsciMag::OsciMag(const Oscillator& osc, const Magnifier& mag)
: Oscillator(osc), Magnifier(mag) {}

OsciMag::OsciMag(const AdvancingOscillator& osc, const Magnifier& mag)
: AdvancingOscillator(osc), Magnifier(mag) {}

OsciMag::OsciMag(const ViralOscillator& osc, const Magnifier& mag)
: ViralOscillator(osc), Magnifier(mag) {}
```

The problem here is twofold:

1. that the program doesn't compile. Two errors are thrown, one for each of the copy constructors that does not accept type Oscillator. They read "error: type ‘[derived oscillator]’ is not a direct base of ‘OsciMag’
2. I'm fairly certain that since the dereferenced pointer is typed to the base class Oscillator it will invoke the first copy constructor.

What I need to do here is get the OsciMag class to be instantiated with either an Oscillator, an AdvancingOscillator, or a ViralOscillator so that in my main program I can have a heterogeneous collection.

Comment: They are not copy constructors.

Comment: copy constructors should take only one parameter and type of the parameter should be const reference to the same class. Something like this `MyClass(const MyClass& obj)`

Comment: thank you for correcting me. my terminology is incorrect but the question remains the same